# How to get the summarized sizes of directories and their subdirectories?

Tags: linux, unix, console

Let's say I want to get the size of each directory of a Linux file system. When I use `ls -la` I don't really get the summarized size of the folders.

If I use `df` I get the size of each mounted file system but that also doesn't help me. And with `du` I get the size of each subdirectory and the summary of the whole file system.

But I want to have only the summarized size of each directory within the ROOT folder of the file system. Is there any command to achieve that?

Comment: The `--total` flag was helpful for me. E.g. `du -sh --total applications/*`. https://askubuntu.com/a/465436/48214

Answer (score 614, accepted):

This does what you're looking for:

```
du -sh /*
```

What this means:

- `-s` to give only the total for each command line argument.
- `-h` for human-readable suffixes like `M` for megabytes and `G` for gigabytes (optional).
- `/*` simply expands to all directories (and files) in `/`.

  *Note: dotfiles are not included; run `shopt -s dotglob` to include those too.*

Also useful is sorting by size:

```
du -sh /* | sort -h
```

Here:

- `-h` ensures that `sort` interprets the human-readable suffixes correctly.

Comment: If you have dot-directories in the root directory, you can use `shopt -s dotglob` to include them in the count.

Comment: It's very usefull, because it's simple and you can place what path you want instead of `/*`, e.g. `./` for current directory or `./*` for each item in current directory.

Comment: @psur or you can use `./*/` to get only subfolders and not all items

Comment: Sorted version: `du -sh /* | sort -h`

Comment: Nice tip on the `sort -h`

Comment: If you're using alpine, `-h` isn't an available flag on `sort`. `sort -nr` should get you the same result, leading to `du -sh /* | sort -nr`.

Comment: @c1phr If your `sort` doesn't have `-h`, you need to leave it off from `du` as well, otherwise the sorting will mix up kilo/mega/gigabytes. `du -s /* | sort -nr`.

Comment: This should throw the top ten of biggest directories: 
`du -hS /var/lib/docker | sort -rh | head -10`

Comment: I've ended with `du -hs /* | sort -hr`. It outputs sizes in readable format (5GB, 6.6M) and sorts values descending.

Comment: This does not show hidden folder.  To get all folder:  `du -sh .[^.]* *  | sort -h`

Comment: How would you adjust this answer to ignore files, and ONLY show directory sizes?

Comment: @rlittles That would be a good topic for a new question, but: `find / -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec du -sh '{}' \; | sort -h`

Comment: To include hidden files, use ```du -sh $(ls -A)``` after entering that directory.

Comment: @GautamSreekumar That only works if none of the file names contain spaces. `(shopt -s dotglob; du -sh *)` will do the trick more safely.

Answer (score 102):

I often need to find the biggest directories, so to get a sorted list containing the 20 biggest dirs I do this:

```
du -m /some/path | sort -nr | head -n 20
```

In this case the sizes will be reported in megabytes.

Comment: Here's a way to get it more readable du -sh /some/path | sort -hr | head -n 20

Comment: @Xedecima the problem with using h is the sort doesn't know how to handle different sizes.  For example 268K is sorted higher than 255M, and both are sorted higher than 2.7G

Comment: The -h (human readable) argument on the 'sort' command should properly read these values. Just like du's -h flag exports them. Depending on what you're running I'm guessing.

Comment: Works in Ubuntu 16.04.  Nice tip.

Comment: sudo du -haxt 1G / | sort -hr | head -30

Answer (score 33):

I like to use [**Ncdu**](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) for that, you can use the cursor to navigate and drill down through the directory structure it works really well.

Comment: Awesome. Keywords: du meets ncurses. You can use `b` to drop into a shell in the directory.

Answer (score 20):

The existing answers are very helpful, maybe some beginner (like me) will find this helpful as well.

1. Very basic loop, but for me this was a good start for some other size related operations:

   ```
   for each in $(ls) ; do du -hs "$each" ; done
   ```
2. Very similar to the first answer and nearly the same result as 1.), but it took me some time to understand the difference of * to ./* if in a subdirectory:

   ```
   du -sh ./*
   ```

Comment: `for each` does not work as it appends console characters (eg `\033[`) to the list of folders

Comment: @machineaddict not sure what you mean. I use this all the time, works for me just fine.

Comment: try to run your command starting with `for each`. it will not work

Comment: i run the command exactly as written here. starting with for each. works.

Answer (score 10):

The following `du` invocation should work on BSD systems:

```
du -d 1 /
```

Comment: My `du` (Ubuntu 10.4) doesn't have a `-d` option. What system are you on?

Comment: On my openSUSE it doesn't have a -d option either :(

Comment: OK, then it's a BSD option only (I'm on OS X).

Comment: Right portable option combination on BSD/*NIX is `du -sk /*`. I hate the `-k` stuff soooo much. Linux' `-h` totally rocks.

Comment: in other systems, its `--max-depth`

Comment: Personal plea: please never parse the output of _ls_. Just use ordinary bash filename exopansion. A simple `for f in *` is safer, more accurate, faster etc.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't easy. The `du` command either shows files and folders (default) or just the sizes of all items which you specify on the command line (option `-s`).

To get the largest items (files and folders), sorted, with human readable sizes on Linux:

```
du -h | sort -h
```

This will bury you in a ton of small files. You can get rid of them with `--threshold` (1 MB in my example):

```
du --threshold=1M -h | sort -h
```

The advantage of this command is that it includes hidden dot folders (folders which start with `.`).

If you really just want the folders, you need to use `find` but this can be very, very slow since `du` will have to scan many folders several times:

```
find . -type d -print0 | sort -z | xargs --null -I '{}' du -sh '{}' | sort -h
```

Comment: --threshold
^^^ this option is not availavle on linux

Comment: @podarok It's available on OpenSUSE 13.2 Linux. Try to find a more recent version of your distribution or compile a more recent version of the package yourself.

Comment: It doen't work on Ubuntu LTS (14.04). It is the most recent one ))

Comment: @podarok Which version of GNU coreutils? Mine is 8.24.

Comment: Sorry. It was not on Ubuntu 14.04. It was Centos 6.6. Lost in consoles....

Comment: Yes, that can be very slow. But you can cache the output from a single find and work from that. No need to access the filesystem several times.

Comment: @Hennes: How do you cache file sizes in a shell script?

Comment: Caching might have been a bad term. I was thinking of something like done in this port http://superuser.com/a/597173/121352 where we scan the disks contents once into a mapping and then continue using data from that mapping rather than hitting the disk again.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to check out [xdiskusage](http://xdiskusage.sourceforge.net/). Will give you the same information, but shown graphically, plus allows to drill down (very useful). There are other similar utilities for KDE and even Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware, that you can't compare directories with `du` on different systems/machines without getting sure, both share the same blocksize of the filesystem. This might count if you rsync some files from a linux machine to a nas and you want to compare the synced directory on your own. You might get different results with `du` because of different blocksizes....

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ls` in conjunction with `awk`:

```
ls -al * | awk 'BEGIN {tot=0;} {tot = tot + $5;} END {printf ("%.2fMb\n",tot/1024/1024);}'
```

The output of `ls` is piped to `awk`. `awk` starts processing the data. Standard delimiter is space. The sum variable `tot` is initialised to zero; the following statement is executed for each row/line outputted by `ls`. It merely increments `tot` with the size. `$5` stands for fifth column (outputted by `ls`). At the end we divide by (1024*1024) to sum in megabytes.

If you would convert this into a script or function (.bashrc) you can also use it to get the size of certain subsets of directories, according to filetypes.

If you want system wide information, `kdirstat` may came in handy!

Comment: I agree one can expand this example and do tricks like getting the size of "certain subsets of directories, according to filetypes" etc.; it may seem a good starting point. Nevertheless this solution is flawed from the start. To every user who would like to use this method I recommend reading answers and comments to [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/108618) as well as the [article linked there](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). I don't say you cannot do it at all. Know the limitations, that's all.