# Recursively chown all files that are owned by a specific user

Tags: macos, unix, permissions

Is it possible to find and chown all files that a specific user owns? I did a bunch of things as the wrong user and need to give the correct user ownership of the files.

Is there a recursive and conditional way I can chown a bunch of files and directories?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use this portable find command with something like this.

```
find . -user old-user -exec chown new-user:new-group {} \;
```

You can expand this to find specific files with -iname options (non POSIX but available on OSX)

```
find . -iname '*.html' -user www-data -exec chown www-data:www-data {} \;
```

The . stands for the current folder and below, so you could use a specific path as a base.

```
find /var/www/ -iname '*.html' -user www-data -exec chown www-data:www-data {} \;
```

Comment: What I was looking for.  But just to note that the options after the chown `new-user:new-user` should probably say `new-user:new-group`

Comment: I'm guessing the curly brackets should be in quotes to properly handle paths with spaces. So ```find . -user old-user -exec chown new-user:new-group "{}" \;```

Comment: In case anyone else is looking for how to find files *not* owned by a certain user (user's files in a home directory that are not owned by that user), you can add '!' to the `-user other-user` section to find the opposite. For example, `find . ! -user other-user`.

Comment: Often the above is more useful when you add `-group old-group`. That way you can preserve group ownership (admin, staff, sillyothergroupname)

Comment: ps - chown may require sudo

Answer (score 26):

You can use

```
chown --from=CURRENT_OWNER:CURRENT_GROUP -R new_owner:new_group  *
```

From the manual `chown --help`:

```
  --from=CURRENT_OWNER:CURRENT_GROUP
                     change the owner and/or group of each file only if
                     its current owner and/or group match those specified
                     here.  Either may be omitted, in which case a match
                     is not required for the omitted attribute.
```

**edit**: This, of course, only works on **linux** and most UNIces. For OSX (which is based on BSD) see the solution of @StephenTrapped.

Comment: +1 but that won't work on OSX, its `chown` doesn't have that option, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/chown.8.html).

Comment: Oops, indeed, i missed the tag osx :) Voted @StephenTrapped up.

Comment: `chown --from=CURRENT_OWNER:CURRENT_GROUP -R new_owner:new_group  *` will skip hidden files in the folder command is ran, however `chown --from=CURRENT_OWNER:CURRENT_GROUP -R new_owner:new_group  .` works for the hidden files in the parent folder too.

Answer (score 5):

The `-h` option of chown changes the permission of the symbolic link files themselves and not just the target.

Which could be crucial when doing this on software binary folders, which use symoblic links to switch between versions.

`find . -user old-user -exec chown -h new-user:new-group {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

Linux answers...
To answer the question explicitly:

To **only** change **user owner** of this **folder** and **everything within it** owned by a **specific user**:

```
sudo chown --from=ownerOld -Rc ownerNew  /this_is_my_path/
```

A few variations to help understanding of syntax which help protect you from catastrophe:

To **only** change **user owner** of everything within a **folder** (not the folder itself) owned by a **specific user**:

```
sudo chown --from=ownerOld -Rc ownerNew  /this_is_my_path/*
```

To **only** change **user owner** of this **folder** and **everything within it** owned by a **specific user & group**:

```
sudo chown --from=ownerOld:groupOld -Rc ownerNew  /this_is_my_path/
```

To change **user & group owners** of everything within a **folder** (not the folder itself) owned by a **specific user**:

```
sudo chown --from=ownerOld -Rc ownerNew:groupNew  /this_is_my_path/*
```

To **only** change **group owners** of this **folder** and **everything within it** owned by a **specific group**:

```
sudo chown --from=:groupOld -Rc :groupNew  /this_is_my_path/
```

To **only** change **group owners** of everything within a **folder** (not the folder itself) owned by a **specific user & group**:

```
sudo chown --from=ownerOld:groupOld -Rc :groupNew  /this_is_my_path/*
```

do not use the ":" or place the group name if you do not wish the group to change.
also you will need to be the owner and have write access so sudo is probably required.
Remember this is a dangerous command DO NOT run on root "/"
If you get it wrong you are in a world of hurt.
Triple check it before you execute it.

switch c is to show changes.
switch R is recursive

/path/* will not pick up hidden files.